# theme overrides geom="pointrange"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code below, I am able to create the following dot plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$vs = as.factor(mtcars$vs)


    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill = vs)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', binwidth = 1, stackdir='center', dotsize = .5, alpha = .5, position=position_dodge(0.25))     
    p + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,
                   fun.args = list(mult=1),         
    geom="pointrange", color=c("black", "red", "black", "red", "black"),
    size = 1, show.legend = F, position=position_dodge(0.25))
p
```

[image]

However, if I were to add a theme `p + theme_bw()`, the `geom=pointrange`, features disappear (see screenshot below). Any idea on how I can retain the pointrange information while applying a theme?

[image]

Comment: Is there a package outside of `ggplot2` trhat you're using? I am struggling to get your code to work

Comment: I'm also struggling to recreate the first plot using your code. Can you tidy it up, improve the formatting , remove the comments and make sure it runs without error. For one thing, you must have converted `vs` to a factor.

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. As I would expect adding theme_bw does not remove the point range. Maybe it's because you forgot to assign to p? Try p + stat_summary() + theme_bw() or p <- p + stat_summary; p + theme_bw()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you aren't storing the plot in `p` when you add `stat_summary` so you are just seeing the plot before you run `stat_summary`. This is why the bottom plot is what shows up when you run `p`. What you need to do is

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill = vs)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', binwidth = 1, stackdir='center', dotsize = .5, alpha = .5, position=position_dodge(0.25)) +
  theme_bw() 
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,
                 fun.args = list(mult=1),         
                 geom="pointrange", color=c("black", "red", "black", "red", "black"),
                 size = 1, show.legend = F, position=position_dodge(0.25)) 
p
```

and when you run `p` you will get the following result
[image: example]

Comment: THANKS! What a noob mistake. My apologies for wasting your (and the community's) time. (I actually figured out the issue myself after stepping away from the problem, and I came to the same conclusion as you just when you posted your reply. Thanks again!)

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you!